# Why the Meta Description of Website's Homepage Not Showing on Bing?

Tags: bing, meta-description

I have been doing SEO for a website of my client. I have added the meta description of all pages with All-in-One SEO plug-in about a month ago.

However, the meta descriptions of some of the pages are not being displayed on Bing. In case of the home page, Bing only shows "© 2015, name of the company, All rights reserved."

On the other hand, Google is showing all the descriptions perfectly.

Why Bing is not showing the meta description? Will you please help me to find the solution?

Comment: Bing can take months, months, and more months.

Comment: Does Bing necessarily show the exact meta description? It doesn't for me. And neither does Google (by design).

Comment: Google doesn't show full meta description if the number of words is more than 160. In this case, only the first 160 words will be shown, and the remaining words will not be displayed. Same thing applies for Bing. However, I have learnt that increasing the number of words more than 160 in meta description will not be bad for SEO provided that the relevant, high traffic keywords are being used.

Comment: Google tailers the description in the SERPs to what the user has searched for, sometimes this is completely different to the actual meta description on the page. Also, the meta description does not influence ranking (if that is what you are implying by "SEO"?). However, it can influence click-through rates.

Comment: Yes, I know that meta description has no effect on ranking, but it is crucial for click through rates.

Comment: Still waiting for a great answer.